# find possible combinations with specific condition

Tags: arrays, matlab, combinations, combinatorics

I want to calculate all possible combinations of 1:16 with 10 subsets.

```
combos = combntns(1:16,10)
```

But the condition is that the returned combos should have minimum 1 member of the following vectors:

```
V1=1:4,V2=5:8,V3=9:12,V4=13:16,
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With that problem size you can afford to generate all combinations and then select those that meet the requirements:

```
n = 16;  %// number of elements to choose from
c = 10;  %// combination size
s = 4;   %// size of each group (size of V1, V2 etc)

combos = nchoosek(1:n, c); 
ind = all(any(any(bsxfun(@eq, combos, reshape(1:n, 1,1,s,[])),2),3),4);
combos = combos(ind,:);
```

This can be generalized for **generic elements** and **arbitrary condition vectors**, assuming **all vectors are the same size**:

```
elements = 1:16;                    %// elements to choose from
c = 10;                             %// combination size
vectors = {1:4, 5:8, 9:12, 13:16};  %// cell array of vectors

s = numel(vectors{1});
combos = nchoosek(elements, c); 
ind = all(any(any(bsxfun(@eq, combos, reshape(cat(1,vectors{:}).', 1,1,s,[])),2),3),4); %'
combos = combos(ind,:);
```

Comment: Nice solution, but this would fail if any of the V-vectors change... I don't know if that's a possibilty, probably not I guess. I was working on solution for the general case with random V-vectors, but I couldn't avoid a loop (which makes it much less fun). I've closed MATLAB now, since I guess this solves OP's question =)

Comment: @StewieGriffin Thanks! It could be done for arbitrary vectors as long as they are all the same size. I've added that

Comment: ... I don't have MATLAB running, but I guess this condition must be true too? `mod(numel(elements),vector{k}) == 0`.Anyway, nice solution for (almost) general vectors) =)

Comment: @StewieGriffin Do you mean `mod(numel(elements),numel(vectors{1}))==0` ? That's not really necessary. For example, I've checked with `vectors = {1:3, 6:8, 9:11, 12:14}` and it works

Comment: .... and the size of all vectors must be equal, because of `cat(...)`. It's a probable scenario if it was combinations of 1:17 (the last vector could for instance be 13:17, or just 17 by itself. Even though I'm nitpicking here, I guess this solves OP's question.